# Electron snap app packaged with snapcraft GPU disabled on Raspberry Pi

Tags: electron, electron-builder, snapcraft

I’ve been going around in circles for hours trying to figure out why my electron app build with electron-builder and packaged as a snap does not have any  GPU acceleration enabled. Iv googled and searched forums for ages and im still stuck, would love some help here.

As you can see from the attached image, all acceleration has been disabled. The app runs terribly as a result.

[image]

It looks like theres some sort of driver issue as im seeing in the logs:

- libGL Error: Failed to load driver: vc4
- MESA-LOADER: failed to open vc4
- vkCreateInstance: Found no drivers!

Im using the standard plugs as mentioned in the builder docs here: https://www.electron.build/configuration/snap.html 1

Also tried adding the **libglu1-mesa** package to stage packages, which I picked up from this article: Adding OpenGL/GPU support to a snap (https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/adding-opengl-gpu-support-to-a-snap/6273)

Im using electron-builder however and I cannot see a way to specify the “desktop-glib-only” part of that config in the electron-builder config (config in above link)

If I run standard chromium that is installed on the Raspberry Pi, and check the GPU status there, all GPU hardware acceleration is enabled and looks normal. So this seems to be snapcraft related.  I have asked on the snapcraft forums and got no reply.

I feel like this should be a pretty common issue with anyone building electron apps with snaps, what am I missing here? can anyone assist before i pull all my hair out?

Thanks in advance

More info

- Raspberry Pi 4B / Latest Raspberry Pi OS
- The snap in question: vuepilot (https://www.vuepilot.com/download)

Context (The full trace on app start up):

> libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open vc4 (search paths
> /snap/vuepilot/101/gnome-platform/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri) libGL
> error: failed to load driver: vc4 libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to
> open vc4 (search paths
> /snap/vuepilot/101/gnome-platform/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri) libGL
> error: failed to load driver: vc4 libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to
> open swrast (search paths
> /snap/vuepilot/101/gnome-platform/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri) libGL
> error: failed to load driver: swrast 11:13:27.923 âº SNAP env is
> defined, updater is disabled 11:13:27.935 âº checkForUpdatesAndNotify
> called, downloadPromise is null
> [2967773:0212/111327.935597:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)]
> Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289:
> Could not create a backing OpenGL context. ERR: Display.cpp:1056
> (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create
> a backing OpenGL context.
> [2967773:0212/111327.936900:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver
> message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL
> context. [2967773:0212/111327.937188:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)]
> eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying
> next display type
> [2967773:0212/111327.944836:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)]
> Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289:
> Could not create a backing OpenGL context. ERR: Display.cpp:1056
> (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create
> a backing OpenGL context.
> [2967773:0212/111327.945113:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver
> message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL
> context. [2967773:0212/111327.945604:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)]
> eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
> [2967773:0212/111327.945902:ERROR:gl_display.cc(829)] Initialization
> of all EGL display types failed.
> [2967773:0212/111327.946236:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)]
> GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
> [2967773:0212/111328.003820:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)]
> Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289:
> Could not create a backing OpenGL context. ERR: Display.cpp:1056
> (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create
> a backing OpenGL context.
> [2967773:0212/111328.004147:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver
> message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL
> context. [2967773:0212/111328.004316:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)]
> eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying
> next display type
> [2967773:0212/111328.008252:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)]
> Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289:
> Could not create a backing OpenGL context. ERR: Display.cpp:1056
> (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create
> a backing OpenGL context.
> [2967773:0212/111328.008547:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver
> message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL
> context. [2967773:0212/111328.008692:ERROR:gl_display.cc(795)]
> eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
> [2967773:0212/111328.008826:ERROR:gl_display.cc(829)] Initialization
> of all EGL display types failed.
> [2967773:0212/111328.008966:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)]
> GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
> [2967773:0212/111328.014692:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(196)] Exiting GPU
> process due to errors during initialization libGL error: MESA-LOADER:
> failed to open vc4 (search paths
> /snap/vuepilot/101/gnome-platform/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri) libGL
> error: failed to load driver: vc4 libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to
> open vc4 (search paths
> /snap/vuepilot/101/gnome-platform/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri) libGL
> error: failed to load driver: vc4 libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to
> open swrast (search paths
> /snap/vuepilot/101/gnome-platform/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/dri) libGL
> error: failed to load driver: swrast
> [2967818:0212/111328.386543:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)]
> Display.cpp:1056 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289:
> Could not create a backing OpenGL context. ERR: Display.cpp:1056
> (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create
> a backing OpenGL context.
> [2967818:0212/111328.387101:ERROR:gl_display.cc(520)] EGL Driver
> message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL
> context.
> message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.

Comment: Screen shots are bad enough. Photos of screen shots are far worse. Photos of screen shots complete with Moire patterns, geometric distortions are amongst the worst possible presentation. And your question is not about programming, so it's off-topic anyway.

Comment: A question about packaging software developed in a popular javascript framework (electron and electron builder) is off topic? i understand the question is not directly about a programming issue but it is directly related to a software engineering problem.
Your unhelpful and rude response is the reason why engineers aren't using tools like stack overflow anymore.   Just say nothing at all if you have nothing useful to add. There is no reason to be a jerk, it doesn't help anyone

Comment: I made a mistake - your question is on topic. Bad presentation helps no-one. If you take more time to raise the standard of your question above the sea of junk that permeates this site, you're more likely to get an answer. As you say - there's no reason to be a jerk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iv managed to solve this after days of searching and with some assistance from GitHub Copilot

For anyone else experiencing this same issue, I was able to solve it by adding some missing packages to my `electron-builder.yaml` under `stagePackages`.

Here's my stagePackages block from my config file

```
  stagePackages:
    - default
    - libglu1-mesa
    - libtinfo5
    - libvulkan1
```

- **libglu1-mesa:** provides the GPU driver files
- **libtinfo5:** Not sure what this is for, but I got an error that it was required
- **libvulkan1:** Installs other Vulkan drivers that were also being complained about